# I want to change a text to display the level in my game in unity3d using an "int valueLevel"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a quiz game in Unity3d and I would like to show in which level the player is depending the questions he/she has answered.Just so that I can see if it works I was trying to make every question count as a Level(and afterwards I would figure it out).I know which lines of code I want to use but I don't know where to put them in order to work properly.

these are the lines I want to use:

```
levelValue = levelValue + 1;
Level.text = "Level:" + levelValue.ToString();
```

this is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Question[] questions;
private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;

private Question currentQuestion;

public Text Level;

[SerializeField]
private Text factText;

[SerializeField]
private Text trueAnswerText;
[SerializeField]
private Text falseAnswerText;

[SerializeField]
private Animator animator;

[SerializeField]
private float timeBetweenQuestions = 1f;

int i = 0;
int levelValue = 0;



void Start()
{

    if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
    {
        unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
    }

    SetCurrentQuestion();


}


void SetCurrentQuestion()
{
    int questionIndex = i;
    currentQuestion = unansweredQuestions[questionIndex];
    i = i + 1;




    factText.text = currentQuestion.fact;


    if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
    {
        trueAnswerText.text = "ΣΩΣΤΟ";
        falseAnswerText.text = "ΛΑΘΟΣ";
    }else
    {
        trueAnswerText.text = "ΛΑΘΟΣ";
        falseAnswerText.text = "ΣΩΣΤΟ";
    }


}

IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion ()
{
    unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenQuestions);

    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);


}

public void UserSelectTrue ()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("True");
    if (currentQuestion.isTrue)
    {
        Debug.Log("CORRECT!");
    }else
    {
        Debug.Log("WRONG!");
    }

    StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
}

public void UserSelectFalse()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("False");
    if (!currentQuestion.isTrue)
    {
        Debug.Log("CORRECT!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("WRONG!");
    }

    StartCoroutine(TransitionToNextQuestion());
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? If you want to change the level whenever you change question then you just need to work out where you change question and put the code there... From a quick glance at your code `TransitionToNextQuestion ` seems to be when you change the question on screen and `SetCurrentQuestion` seems to be where you change the value of `i` which seems to be your question number. I don't know whether there are pros and cons to each but given you don't actually want to do this in the long run it seems a bit of an unhelpful question to be asking...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code is the same for every question, I suggest you set the

```
int levelValue = 0;
```

to static like this:

```
private static int levelValue;
```

In C# the default value of an uninitialized int is Zero.

The increment of levelValue should happen right before you change level if you want the counter to start from 0 (For example count how many questions you have answered)  OR in the beginning of the script if you want the levels to count from 1 (For example what question you are right now).

In first case it should be something like this:

```
IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion ()
{
    unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenQuestions);
    levelValue++;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

or in the later case:

```
void Start()
{

    if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.Count == 0)
    {
        unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
    }
    levelValue++;
    SetCurrentQuestion();
}
```

Now about where to set the Text value, you can either put it in the Update method of unity

```
void Update(){
    Level.Text= String.Format("Level: {0}",levelValue);
}
```

or in your Start method.

Also a tip for your code:
use the operator ++ when you want to increase an int value by one.
example

```
i++; //THIS has the same effect as this  i = i + 1;
```

Good luck with your project and feel free to contact me for any additional information or questions you might have.

Comment: It works but what can I do if I want the levels to change per 3 questions.I have made only 6 question(so it can be easy to manage,later I will put more).I have written this but it doesn't seem to work :              
    IEnumerator TransitionToNextQuestion ()
    {
        unansweredQuestions.Remove(currentQuestion);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenQuestions);
        if (i==3 || i==4 || 1==5)
        {
            levelValue++;}
  SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

        
    }

Comment: Then easily enought you can divide the levelValue by 3 and keep the integer part.
example: 
    int levelOutput = (int)levelValue/3;
    Level.Text= String.Format("Level: {0}",levelOutput );

Comment: Hi I don't know if you remember this but I have another problem with unity.I have submitted a new question.If you can please check it out